# Plotly: group trace in legend and removing horizontal labels

Tags: python, python-3.x, plotly, legend, plotly-python

I'm using Plotly to produce a similar graph from https://plotly.com/python/horizontal-bar-charts/, section "Color Palette for Bar Chart".

Here's the code, based on the reference link, but with few modifications (values in `x_data` and `showlegend = True`) to show my problem:

```
import plotly.graph_objects as go

top_labels = ['Strongly<br>agree', 'Agree', 'Neutral', 'Disagree',
              'Strongly<br>disagree']

colors = ['rgba(38, 24, 74, 0.8)', 'rgba(71, 58, 131, 0.8)',
          'rgba(122, 120, 168, 0.8)', 'rgba(164, 163, 204, 0.85)',
          'rgba(190, 192, 213, 1)']

x_data = [[21, 30, 21, 16, 12],
          [24, 31, 19, 15, 11],
          [27, 26, 23, 11, 13],
          [29, 24, 15, 18, 14]]

y_data = ['The course was effectively<br>organized',
          'The course developed my<br>abilities and skills ' +
          'for<br>the subject', 'The course developed ' +
          'my<br>ability to think critically about<br>the subject',
          'I would recommend this<br>course to a friend']

fig = go.Figure()

for i in range(0, len(x_data[0])):
    for xd, yd in zip(x_data, y_data):
        fig.add_trace(go.Bar(
            x=[xd[i]], y=[yd],
            orientation='h',
            marker=dict(
                color=colors[i],
                line=dict(color='rgb(248, 248, 249)', width=1)
            )
        ))

fig.update_layout(
    xaxis=dict(
        showgrid=False,
        showline=False,
        showticklabels=False,
        zeroline=False,
        domain=[0.15, 1]
    ),
    yaxis=dict(
        showgrid=False,
        showline=False,
        showticklabels=False,
        zeroline=False,
    ),
    barmode='stack',
    paper_bgcolor='rgb(248, 248, 255)',
    plot_bgcolor='rgb(248, 248, 255)',
    margin=dict(l=120, r=10, t=140, b=80),
    showlegend=True, ###changed here
)

annotations = []

for yd, xd in zip(y_data, x_data):
    # labeling the y-axis
    annotations.append(dict(xref='paper', yref='y',
                            x=0.14, y=yd,
                            xanchor='right',
                            text=str(yd),
                            font=dict(family='Arial', size=14,
                                      color='rgb(67, 67, 67)'),
                            showarrow=False, align='right'))
    # labeling the first percentage of each bar (x_axis)
    annotations.append(dict(xref='x', yref='y',
                            x=xd[0] / 2, y=yd,
                            text=str(xd[0]) + '%',
                            font=dict(family='Arial', size=14,
                                      color='rgb(248, 248, 255)'),
                            showarrow=False))
    # labeling the first Likert scale (on the top)
    if yd == y_data[-1]:
        annotations.append(dict(xref='x', yref='paper',
                                x=xd[0] / 2, y=1.1,
                                text=top_labels[0],
                                font=dict(family='Arial', size=14,
                                          color='rgb(67, 67, 67)'),
                                showarrow=False))
    space = xd[0]
    for i in range(1, len(xd)):
            # labeling the rest of percentages for each bar (x_axis)
            annotations.append(dict(xref='x', yref='y',
                                    x=space + (xd[i]/2), y=yd,
                                    text=str(xd[i]) + '%',
                                    font=dict(family='Arial', size=14,
                                              color='rgb(248, 248, 255)'),
                                    showarrow=False))
            # labeling the Likert scale
            if yd == y_data[-1]:
                annotations.append(dict(xref='x', yref='paper',
                                        x=space + (xd[i]/2), y=1.1,
                                        text=top_labels[i],
                                        font=dict(family='Arial', size=14,
                                                  color='rgb(67, 67, 67)'),
                                        showarrow=False))
            space += xd[i]

fig.update_layout(annotations=annotations)

fig.show()
```

[Bar Chart showing multiple equal traces as legend](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cR3FP.png)

Here's what I've got:

I'd like to:
remove these horizontal labels on top, since there are 0% for some of them and so the text alignment gets weird (know that `top_labels = ['','','','','']` would do the trick, but then how to show that previous content in legend?) and then show the right labels in legend -- that is, instead of showing 4 times the same color for traces, show each only once with appropriate title.

Like this: [Bar Chart with unique labesl in legend](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hDniE.png)

How can I do that properly?

[Showing these labels instead of `trace 0`, ... , `trace 19`,  when hovering over the plot is of interest too.]

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work:

```py
import plotly.graph_objects as go

top_labels = ['Strongly<br>agree', 'Agree', 'Neutral', 'Disagree',
              'Strongly<br>disagree']

colors = ['rgba(38, 24, 74, 0.8)', 'rgba(71, 58, 131, 0.8)',
          'rgba(122, 120, 168, 0.8)', 'rgba(164, 163, 204, 0.85)',
          'rgba(190, 192, 213, 1)']

x_data = [[21, 30, 21, 16, 12],
          [24, 31, 19, 15, 11],
          [27, 26, 23, 11, 13],
          [29, 24, 15, 18, 14]]

y_data = ['The course was effectively<br>organized',
          'The course developed my<br>abilities and skills ' +
          'for<br>the subject', 'The course developed ' +
          'my<br>ability to think critically about<br>the subject',
          'I would recommend this<br>course to a friend']

fig = go.Figure()

for i in range(0, len(x_data[0])):
    for idx, (xd, yd) in enumerate(zip(x_data, y_data)):
        fig.add_trace(go.Bar(
            x=[xd[i]], y=[yd],
            orientation='h',
            marker=dict(
                color=colors[i],
                line=dict(color='rgb(248, 248, 249)', width=1)
            ),
            name = top_labels[i],
            showlegend = idx == 0
        ))

fig.update_layout(
    xaxis=dict(
        showgrid=False,
        showline=False,
        showticklabels=False,
        zeroline=False,
        domain=[0.15, 1]
    ),
    yaxis=dict(
        showgrid=False,
        showline=False,
        showticklabels=False,
        zeroline=False,
    ),
    barmode='stack',
    paper_bgcolor='rgb(248, 248, 255)',
    plot_bgcolor='rgb(248, 248, 255)',
    margin=dict(l=120, r=10, t=140, b=80),
)

annotations = []

for yd, xd in zip(y_data, x_data):
    # labeling the y-axis
    annotations.append(dict(xref='paper', yref='y',
                            x=0.14, y=yd,
                            xanchor='right',
                            text=str(yd),
                            font=dict(family='Arial', size=14,
                                      color='rgb(67, 67, 67)'),
                            showarrow=False, align='right'))
    # labeling the first percentage of each bar (x_axis)
    annotations.append(dict(xref='x', yref='y',
                            x=xd[0] / 2, y=yd,
                            text=str(xd[0]) + '%',
                            font=dict(family='Arial', size=14,
                                      color='rgb(248, 248, 255)'),
                            showarrow=False))
    space = xd[0]
    for i in range(1, len(xd)):
            # labeling the rest of percentages for each bar (x_axis)
            annotations.append(dict(xref='x', yref='y',
                                    x=space + (xd[i]/2), y=yd,
                                    text=str(xd[i]) + '%',
                                    font=dict(family='Arial', size=14,
                                              color='rgb(248, 248, 255)'),
                                    showarrow=False))
            space += xd[i]

fig.update_layout(annotations=annotations)

fig.show()
```

The idea is you show legend only once for each type of top_label (you can do that by only displaying it for the very first time)

Comment: Works just perfectly! Tanks a lot =]